# How to have main expandable row for data with children in antd table

Tags: reactjs, antd

I have a nested data .and I have to show that data in `antd` tree table. I want to have that expanding icon to  be placed in a separate column, with row selection like

https://ant.design/components/table/#components-table-demo-expand

not with the first column of the data like this
 https://ant.design/components/table/#components-table-demo-expand-children

```
const data = [
  {
    key: 1,
    _id: '1',
    name: 'Sara Harrison',
    email: `sara-harrisom${1}@domain.com`,
    messaged: `4 Sep 2019, 11:20:02AM`,
    description: `My name is John NBrown, 1 am ${1}2 years old, living in New York No. ${1} Lake Park.`,
    children: [
      {
        key: '14',
        _id: '1',

        name: 'Sara Harrison s',
        email: `sara3-harrisom${14}@domain.com`,
        messaged: `14 Sep 2019, 11:20:02AM`,
        description: `My name is KLJohn Browne, 14 am ${14}2 years old, living in New York No. ${14} Lake Park.`
      },
      {
        key: '11',
        name: 'Para Harrison',
        email: `Para-harrisom${11}@domain.com`,
        messaged: `4 Sep 2019, 11:20:02AM`,
        description: `My name is JPohn Brown, 11 am ${11}2 years old, living in New York No. ${11} Lake Park.`
      }
    ]
  }
];

<Table
  rowKey={data._id}
  columns={this.columns1}
  rowSelection={this.rowSelection}
  expandedRowRender={(record, index, indent, expanded) => {
    //     this.expanding(record,expanded)
  }}
  onExpand={this.onExpand}
  dataSource={data}
/>
```

Plz Help

Comment: Next time please check that the code you posted is valid (no syntax errors) and readable.

Answer (score 1):

If you using `Columns.children` you can't.

The possible ways is an inner table within the `expandedRowRender` or implement one yourself.

```
const tableProps = {
  expandedRowRender: record => (
    <Table {...tableProps} columns={columns} dataSource={data} />
  )
};
```

[image: Edit Q-57916977-TableRowRender]

Comment: Same thing I tried .but there is one problem .If I select row of nested table checkmark is not apearing for checkbox in  main column of the table

Comment: I don't know what your tried to do without seeing any code, post sandbox your question is incomplete

Comment: They are two different tables, you need to share some state between them

Comment: Ok .. are u sure that we can achieve it through state

Comment: Yea, your rendering two unrelated components, how will the main `Table` will be aware of its inner one

Comment: ok.. Implemented using div .because  the nested table css was breaking .

Answer (score 0):

You can add an empty column (no data, no title etc) and it should do the trick.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).